# Magento2 multicreate customer API

Tags: api, magento2-dev-beta

Using `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerRepository` Save method we can create single customer with the attributes in `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface`with single API request.

But how can we create multiple customers at a time with single API request.

If i send multiple customers objects in a single request its giving error expecting the `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` attributes.

So how can i create API with `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerRepository` Save method with array of `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` attributes

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option.

- Send many request
- Create service that gets list of customers and save it use Customer Repository

Comment: When i use first option its giving error, expecting `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` attributes. For second option please provide example which works

Comment: what is the importance of KEY keyword in api, example https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/CustomerInterface.php#L35 compared to other attributes which do not have KEY keyword

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kandy/dd6592508c5774d9235d

Comment: you are calling customer request api each time for the each customer, but i want to send multiple customers in a single request

Comment: Magento 2 don't have this possibility, but you create simple module for this

Comment: Also looks like you need customer import, not api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29965/discussion-between-prasad-maganti-and-kandy).